# Why does my javascript not update quantity in Opencart category.tpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

In category.tpl Opencart 1.5.x
I'm trying to add quantity to the add to cart button.

```
<div class="cart">
    <input type="text" name="quantity<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="1" size="1" />
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', 'document.form.quantity<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>.value')" class="button" />
</div>
```

If I just put a number in for the second variable of addToCart like

```
addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', 2);
```

This adds quantity 2 fine. Checking the element name in ff shows me the number is coming back from php correctly "quantity6.value", etc. Apparently, but when I click Add to Cart nothing happens. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Just to make it more succinct I changed the line to:
    " onclick="addToCart('', document.getElementById('quantity').value)" class="button" />

But still the button does not appear to do anything on a click. I assume the document.getElementById().. line is not returning the number properly, but I'm not sure of a good way to test it.

Neither does this seem to work:

```
<div class="cart">
    <input type="text" name="quantity<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="1" size="1" onchange="updateQty(<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>);" />

    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', getQty(<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>);)" class="button" />
  </div>
...

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function getQty(num) {
getQty = document.getElementById('quantity' & num).value;

}

function updateQty(num) {
var ibox = document.form.quanity[num].value;
quantity[num] = ibox;
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like for this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a little overdone to be honest. You can do this with one function simply by changing the function on the `onclick` event to `addToCartCategory()` and changing the name to an ID for the quantity box. Something along the lines of

```
<div class="cart">
    <input type="text" id="quantity<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="1" size="1" />

    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCartCategory(<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>)" class="button" />
  </div>
...

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function addToCartCategory(product_id) {
    var qty = $('#quantity' + product_id).val();
    addToCart(product_id, qty);

}
...
</script>
```

Comment: nice, thanks for looking at it. I knew I just wasn't wrapping my head around it correctly.